# Paperjs why I am getting an error on MouseLeave

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I want to create a grid of rectangles that they light up when mouse is over them and I am getting an error on onMouseLeave event (or onMouseEnter, I am not sure yet) of the rect path.

It doesn't happens all the time but mostly when I move the cursor quickly or when the cursor goes outside of the browser.

```
paper-core.js:12475 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_canvasStyle' on string 'grey'
    at fields.<computed> [as fillColor] (paper-core.js:12475:12)
    at item.<computed> [as fillColor] (paper-core.js:12530:16)
    at Path2.<anonymous> (percussions.js?t=1659596246337:30:28)
    at Path2.emit (paper-core.js:705:20)
    at emit (paper-core.js:13349:13)
    at emitMouseEvent (paper-core.js:13364:8)
    at CanvasView2._handleMouseEvent (paper-core.js:13438:6)
    at handleMouseMove (paper-core.js:13230:8)
    at docEvents.<computed> (paper-core.js:13300:4)
```

Here is how I create the scope. I am using ES modules

```js
    let paper = new PaperScope()
    var canvas = document.getElementById('paperjs');
    paper.setup(canvas);
```

Here is the code

```js
let tileSize = Math.floor((window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight) * .025)

for (var y = 0; y < paper.view.size.height; y += tileSize) {
    for (var x = 0; x < paper.view.size.width; x += tileSize) {
        let topLeft = new paper.Point(x, y);
        let radius = new paper.Size(tileSize, tileSize);
        let rect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(topLeft,  radius);
        rect.fillColor = 'white';
        rect.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
            this.fillColor = 'grey'

        })
        rect.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
            this.fillColor = 'white'

        })      
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="paperjs" resize data-paper-hidpi="off"></canvas>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
canvas[resize] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#paperjs {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Any ideas on why I am getting the aforementioned error onMouseLeave ?

Comment: maybe try defining events like : `rect.onMouseLeave = function(event) { ...`

Comment: That was my first implementation. No luck though.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (https://jsfiddle.net/uhmwgL4a/), could you try to reproduce it as a fiddle ?

Comment: I really don't understand why this is not happening on jsFiddle.

Comment: It's maybe related to the paper.js version that you are using or the way your code is setup. Maybe you could try to create a reproduction repository instead ?